# What language was Google written in at the beginning?

Tags: google-search

I wonder what language Larry Page and Sergey Brin wrote Google with?

I'm not talking about the languages that are used today, but about the version they launched from their dorm.

Comment: From their dorm? That sounds like an urban legend. It was their PhD project.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: That would have been some pretty loud dorm: http://geektechnique.org/media/google/googlehardware.html At least they wouldn't have had to worry about heating ...

Comment: some say it was the dorm.. some say it was the garage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Google:

> Some Rough Statistics (from August 29th, 1996)
>
> Total indexable HTML urls: 75.2306 Million
> Total content downloaded: 207.022 gigabytes
> ...
>
> BackRub is written in **Java and Python** and runs on several Sun Ultras and Intel Pentiums running Linux.
>
> The primary database is kept on an Sun Ultra II with 28GB of disk. Scott Hassan and Alan Steremberg have provided a great deal of very talented implementation help. Sergey Brin has also been very involved and deserves many thanks.
>
> -Larry Page page@cs.stanford.edu

Comment: @fayer: Read the article. BackRub was the name of their software before they changed it to Google.